# Has Mister Fantastic ever used his elasticity to impersonate someone?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four

Reed Richards is able to stretch, deform, expand, or compress his entire body or parts thereof into any contiguous shape he wants. Due to this he is able to more or less change his features (though not as well as Mystique).

As quoted from [this well-written Marvel Wiki page](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Reed_Richards_(Earth-616)#Powers):

> - **Shape Changing**: Mister Fantastic can stretch, deform, expand, or compress his entire body or parts thereof into any contiguous shape he can imagine for a variety of uses:
>
>   - **Imitation**: Mister Fantastic may **alter his basic physical features, allowing him to take on the appearance of any other man with similar hair and skin tone**.

#### Has Mister Fantastic ever used his elasticity to impersonate someone?

I read somewhere that Reed had impersonated his mailman of some sort (would like a confirmation of this happening). Other than this, **has Mister Fantastic ever impersonated anyone (else)?**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceebQxWgHis - Deleted scene

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/3fqrgd/are_there_any_examples_of_mr_fantastic/

Comment: Yes, sometimes he impersonate Rocco Siffredi. But just a part...

Comment: I distinctly remember an occasion when a short character in armor was seeking sanctuary from the Skrulls, and Reed squeezed himself down into the armor to trick said Skrulls. Sadly, this is insufficient detail for my Google-fu.

Comment: Perhaps of interest-- in early comics, Superman would sometimes push around his own facial features in order to impersonate someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest movie, he did it when he was buying parts at the store when he was hiding from the government.  Not impersonating someone, that we saw at least, but he was using his powers to change his face.

Answer (score 1):

Not impersonating somebody, but some time ago, during one of the group's perennial efforts to "live a life outside the Fantastic Four", Reed would alter his facial features slightly to help with the cover identity he was using.

Comment: I think I remember that - it would have been from John Byrne's run on the book, circa issues 256-279 (vol. 1, of course), when Reed, Sue and Franklin were living in the burbs (in Connecticut, I think) under the surname "Benjamin" (no Pooh jokes, please), because that would be an easy alias for even Franklin to remember. (technically, making him Franklin Benjamin Benjamin, but we'll let that go).